# Adding Skype Chat in Thunderbird

Tags: skype, thunderbird

I would like to set up Skype on my Thunderbird software.
However I do not see any way to add Skype. This would be really useful and interesting, particularly for professional purposes.
I know it is possible to use third programs or websites to access skype (like imo.im) so I assume there is a way doing it on thunderbird.

Please note that I already contacted Skype Support, and they forwarded me to Thunderbird Support (if necessary, I can provide the logs here). Furthermore I tried to contact thunderbird support but I didn't received answers, explaining why I am asking here.

Thank you all in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Skype chat in any application anymore because when Microsoft bought Skype they shut off XMPP protocol and made their proprietary protocol encrypted so that only their client software can connect.